# Power BI: alias / mapping List / Book

Tags: mapping, powerbi, alias, powerquery, powerbi-desktop

I'm searching for a "Alias" solution. I have different Services in one of my columns and i want to show this services on a map. For this i need a Alias book. Example:

Service Like "*:X1" = Berlin

Service Like "*:X2" = München

and so on ....

Does anyone has an Idea how to handle this easly?

Thanks

-Florian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way to do this is to create a lookup table in Power BI which has the Service values and the corresponding City. You should also extract the relevant details from Service field by using the following calculation:

```
Calc_Key = RIGHT(Service,3)
```

Then you should establish a relationship between the two tables and you should be able to use the city details in the map. Hope this helps.